# Hyperledger Fabric CA Authorization failure

Tags: hyperledger

This is what happens if I run node registerUser.js.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZitZ2.jpg

This is the error log from the CA
https://prnt.sc/pvj8v9

This is my registerUser.js
https://prnt.sc/pvj9kx

My compose-ca.yaml: 
https://prnt.sc/pvjakf

```
My connection.json:

https://pastebin.com/eajGnnP2
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This is how register user flow works.

[image]

Register User:

1. Client will send a register user `Bob` request to CA.
2. CA will create certificates for user `Bob` and it'll send back certificates as a response.
3. Client receive these certificates and save in the wallet. In `balance-transfer` sample it gets saved in `fabric-client-kv-orgname`

You can check the wallet name in `artifacts/orgname.yaml`.

So when you restart the network, these wallet certificates lose their identity as network has no knowledge of them, as a result it throws an error of Authorization.

When I say restart it means you are creating a new network with the same `crypto-config` only the data which was saved in the network is cleared or deleted.

Another scenario is when network is running and you stopped the `CA` and generate new certificates for it and start the `CA` again with same `ca-name`.

In this scenario, the wallet identities will throw an unauthorized error. The users were created by different `CA` and network is trying to verify using the new `CA`.

---

That's why you should delete the wallets whenever you create a new network.

Answer (score 0):

> Certificate signed by unknown authority

This means the CA admin identity has been generated long back ago and mean while you have deployed CA recently

This happens when you create CA and destroy again create CA docker containers

Try to delete the key value store (kvs) folder which was generated automatically and try to register new user

Comment: The KVS store is the crypto-config folder which holds all the certificates? I am regenerating those files in deployment.

Comment: No, it's not that I am not talking about `crypto-config` I am talking about kv store something like this `fabric-client-kv-myorg`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this error is due to the admin identity that you are using is signed by some other certificate authority.

The KVS store is the wallet folder in your project directory. So try deleting all the certificates stored in that folder and then create new user wallets.